# validate WTForm after selectfield choices updated dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

I am creating a flask app and I created a form using WTForms. The form has two SelectFields (dropdowns) and a submit button. I would like the dropdowns to be dynamic - basically, the user will select an option from dropdown A, this will trigger a database query in the background which will return the choices for dropdown B.

I have found some good solutions for this

- [For example, this youtube video shows how to use javascript +
  WTForms to achieve this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2dJuNwlIH0)
- [and this stackoverflow question uses jquery and regular forms.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49969686/2229847)

I ended up using the second answer to the linked stackoverflow question to model my solution. The basic idea is that the jquery calls a flask endpoint which does the database query and returns the new options for the dropdown which are dynamically populated

I want to do some additional processing once the form is submitted, and to do this, I am using `if form.validate_on_submit():` in the index endpoint to wrap the additional processing and to validate the form. None of the answers to this question that I have found have attempted to validate the form. The problem is that the `choices` field on dropdown B are now invalid. I started with some default values, which the validator function expects and then updated the choices dynamically using jquery without updating the choices. As described in the solution, the database query is processed in a different endpoint from the index endpoint where I'm checking the form validation, so it does not have access to these new choices to populate them.

What is the best way to update the choices for the form in the index endpoint (after the choices have been updated) so that the form will be valid on submit?

Some code snippets

jquery (mostly copied from the linked stackoverflow answer)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dropdown_one').change(function(){

          $.getJSON('/_update_dropdown', {
            selected_class: $('#dropdown_one').val()

          }).done(function(data) {
                $('#dropdown_two').html(data.html_string_selected);
           })
        });
      });
    </script>
```

form class

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    dropdown_one = SelectField("Choose an option", choices = [options])
    dropdown_two = SelectField("Choose option based on dropdown one")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

python/flask index endpoint

```
@bp_views.route('', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():        
    form = Form()

    form.dropdown_two.choices = [(None, "Choose item on dropdown one first")] # default value for the second dropdown
        
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # further processing
        # this check fails because the choices have been updated from the default values and the choice isn't valid
    

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

python/flask update endpoint (mostly copied from the linked stackoverflow answer

```
@bp_views.route('/_update_dropdown')
def update_dropdown():
    # the value of the first dropdown (selected by the user)
    selected_class = request.args.get('selected_class', type=str)
    
    # get values for the second dropdown
    updated_values = db.fetch_data(selected_class)

    # create the value sin the dropdown as a html string
    html_string_selected = ''
    for entry in updated_values:
        html_string_selected += '<option value="{}">{}</option>'.format(entry, entry)

    return jsonify(html_string_selected=html_string_selected)
```

Comment: You've figured out your problem, what have you tried (show some code)? What's to stop you running the database query in your index endpoint and  updating the form's choices before you run `validate_on_submit`?

Comment: I think I've explained what I've done so far pretty clearly... I'm not sure what code would be helpful to post as I pretty much did the same thing that was posted in the answer I linked.   I could run the database query on my index endpoint but I would be running the same query twice every time the page loads and I would like to avoid that

Comment: The 2 link you add is not enough, first of all because you oblige who wants to answer to look an entire video or an entire SO post rather than just make it easier and add the code leaving all effort to who is responding. But also, and most importantly I don't think your code is the same. In fact you are stating that you have a 'if feed_type_form.validate_on_submit():'  But in the 2 solutions they don't use it. So please edit your question, add your code and give and example of what outcome you expect from your code.

Comment: I added some code snippets. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well.  My solution was to dynamically create the selected choice on submission so that it could be valid.

This is an example of how it could work:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for k,v in form.data.items():
        if isinstance(form[k].widget, wtforms.widgets.Select):
            form[k].choices = [(form[k].data, form[k].data)]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
```

It should be noted that in this example, validation is being bypassed for SelectFields.  A malicious actor could submit any value they wanted and it would become valid on submission, unless additional server-side steps are taken to limit what choices could be created.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Jonathan Dixon make the choices in the post and set the validate_choice to False can lead to A malicious data

I think in my opinion to solve this you can set validate_choice in default to False then in POST endpoint update the choices values and finally set validate_choice back to True and call validate_on_submit

```
form(FlaskForm):
    SelectField("Choose option based on dropdown one", validate_choice=False)

form.catalogue_id.choices = [(1, 'hi'), (2, 'hi2')] # use query to get data
form.catalogue_id.validate_choice = True
print(form.validate_on_submit())
```

please if this not safe it will be good to notice by comment on my answer