# Get selected option from dynamic dependent dropdown list - using Flask (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to retrieve the selected option on a dynamic dependent dropdown list, but I only get `None` using `request.form.get`. My example generates a dropdown list in the image below:

[image]

The full code to generate the dropdown list is below, and it is based on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978879/how-to-create-chained-selectfield-in-flask-without-refreshing-the-page).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():

    systems = {
        'PlayStation': {'Spyro': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Crash': ['4', '5', '6'], 'Ico': ['7', '8']},
        'N64': {'Mario Kart': ['Mario', 'Luigi'], 'Superman': ['12', '13', '14']}
    }
    
    if request.method == "POST":

        systemGet = request.form.get("system")
        gameGet = request.form.get("game")
        charactersGet = request.form.get("characters")
        
        print(systemGet)
        print(gameGet)
        print(charactersGet)

        return redirect('temp.html')

    return render_template_string(template, systems=systems)
    
    

template = """
<!doctype html>
<form method="POST">
    <select id="system">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <select id="game"></select>
    <select id="characters"></select>
    <button type="submit">Play</button>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";

    var systems = {{ systems|tojson }};

    var form = $('form');
    var system = $('select#system');
    var game = $('select#game');
    var characters = $('select#characters');

    for (var key in systems) {
        system.append($('<option/>', {'value': key, 'text': key}));
    }

    system.change(function(ev) {
        game.empty();
        game.append($('<option/>'));

        var games = systems[system.val()];

        for (var i in games) {
            game.append($('<option/>', {'value': i, 'text': i}));
        }
    });
    
    game.change(function(evV) {
        characters.empty();
        characters.append($('<option/>'));

        var games = systems[system.val()][game.val()];

        for (var i in games) {
            characters.append($('<option/>', {'value': games[i], 'text': games[i]}));
        }
    });

</script>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Edit**:
Including the `name` attribute, as proposed by @vremes, all works. The solution becomes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():

    systems = {
        'PlayStation': {'Spyro': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Crash': ['4', '5', '6'], 'Ico': ['7', '8']},
        'N64': {'Mario Kart': ['Mario', 'Luigi'], 'Superman': ['12', '13', '14']}
    }
    
    if request.method == "POST":

        systemGet = request.form.get("system")
        gameGet = request.form.get("game")
        charactersGet = request.form.get("characters")
        
        print(systemGet)
        print(gameGet)
        print(charactersGet)

        return redirect('temp.html')

    return render_template_string(template, systems=systems)
    
    

template = """
<!doctype html>
<form method="POST">
    <select id="system" name="system">
    </select>
    
    <select id="game" name="game">
    </select>
    
    <select id="characters" name="characters">
    </select>
        
    <button type="submit">Play</button>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";

    var systems = {{ systems|tojson }};

    var form = $('form');
    var system = $('select#system');
    var game = $('select#game');
    var characters = $('select#characters');

    for (var key in systems) {
        system.append($('<option/>', {'value': key, 'text': key}));
    }

    system.change(function(ev) {
        game.empty();
        game.append($('<option/>'));

        var games = systems[system.val()];

        for (var i in games) {
            game.append($('<option/>', {'value': i, 'text': i}));
        }
    });
    
    game.change(function(evV) {
        characters.empty();
        characters.append($('<option/>'));

        var games = systems[system.val()][game.val()];

        for (var i in games) {
            characters.append($('<option/>', {'value': games[i], 'text': games[i]}));
        }
    });

</script>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.form.get` relies on HTML `name` attribute, add `name` attribute to each of your `select` dropdowns, for example:

```html
<!-- request.form.get('system') should work now -->
<select id="system" name="system">
    <option value="mario">Mario</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, @vremes. Now I have a correct result using request.form.get, but got a new error. I edited the original question to show what the problem is.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code and tested it, i'm unable to reproduce your issue, i selected N64 -> Mario Kart, only Mario and Luigi options are shown on my end, i'm using Firefox.

Comment: I suppose the problem is because I'm including all 'characters'/'games' as 'option', but only the 'characters' for each 'game' should be present. Including the delimited 'options' is actually done by the function 'game.change(function(evV)', whenever I decide for a game. So, the code works fine just including 'name="system"', and without including any 'option'. The 'option' inclusion should be handled by the functions.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you mentioned the 'name' attribute. Thank you very much! I edited my question to include the complete fixed code.